# Protect WordPress PDF uploads on nginx

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx

I'm looking to protect WordPress PDF uploads, and restrict their access to users who meet a certain cookie requirement. These users are **not necessarily logged in**, instead we check for certain data in their saved cookies.

I found this article for Apache: http://0to5.com/protecting-wordpress-media-uploads-unless-user-is-logged-in/

It describes how you can execute your own PHP when accessing media. How would I translate that into nginx? Or is there a better way to do restrict PDF access on nginx?